# If and else Spacebars statements in Meteor stopped working

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor suddenly my if and else Spacebars block stopped working and from what I can recall I haven't done anything particular that would result in the change.
I've made a very straightforward helper for the statements and it worked before.

My helper:

```
Template.eventpage.helpers({
  userHasApplied: function () {
    return Meets.findOne({
      "usersApplied": Meteor.userId()
    });
  }
});
```

Then I simply have a statement like this:

```html
{{#if userHasApplied}}
  <h1>This should show up if the user id is in the field usersApplied</h1>
{{else}}
  <h1>Otherwise something else should show up.</h1>
{{/if}}
```

No matter what, this happens: If no user has applied to any Meet, the else statement works, the content in after the `{{else}}` shows up. But if one user applies to one meet, the content in between the `if` tags shows up all the time. Even to meets which the user hasn't applied to.

This worked perfectly before but suddenly it stopped working and I have no idea on where to start looking. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try writing up a short [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/) to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: What happens if you console log that `findOne`?

Comment: If I console log the findOne I get the correct id of my Meet so nothing wrong there.

Comment: Now, without changing anything, the problem is the opposite and the content after the {{else}} block shows up every time instead.